# How do I add "_" to a string after every Capital letter?

Tags: python, string

I would like to add underscore "_" after every capital letter in a string.
For example, If the string is "StackOverFlow", I would like to make it this "_Stack_Over_Flow"

Comment: After or before? Please clarify

Comment: Hi Rahul, please show what you've tried.

Comment: Just a heads up: As a rule, you don't edit the question to add a solution (if it had not been closed, I'd have encouraged adding your own answer if it meaningfully differed from the existing answers); it discourages people from evaluating/voting on the various answers. I've rolled your question back to before you added the answer. As for thanks, feel free to up-vote any helpful answers, not just accept one, and if you have something more detailed than just thanks, feel free to comment on the answer(s) that inspire such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh it's not much but here's a simple way.

```
string = "StackOverFlow"
newString = []
for letters in string:
    if letters.isupper():
        letters = "_"+letters
    newString.append(letters)
print(''.join(newString))
```

Output:

```
_Stack_Over_Flow
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, this was really helpful..
I wanted to solve this without importing any module. Here's complete solution after using inputs from everybody:

word = "StackOverFlow"
new_word = []

if word.islower():
    print(word)
else:
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isupper():
            letter = "_"+letter
            new_word.append(letter)
        else:
            new_word.append(letter)
            
    new_word = ''.join(new_word).lstrip("_")
    print(new_word)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

s = "StackOverFlow"
result = re.sub(r"([A-Z])", r"_\1", s)
```

Comment: Just for funsies, you could also use a lookahead assertion to remove the need to explicitly capture and reinsert the character: `result = re.sub(r"(?=[A-Z])", r"_", s)` Just adds the `?=`, removes the `\1`. Meaningfully faster too (presumably by avoiding extracting capture groups, and making the substitution string non-dynamic); for `s = 'S' * 10`, avoiding the capture group cut runtime for me by ~80% (6.8 µs w/capture, 1.43 µs without, using a precompiled/bound regex's `sub` method to minimize other sources of overhead, e.g. `ssub = re.compile(r"(?=[A-Z])").sub` once, `res = ssub('_', s)`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` with `isupper`:

```
In [1722]: s = "StackOverFlow"

In [1740]: l = []

In [1741]: for c,i in enumerate(list(s)):
      ...:     if i.isupper():
      ...:         l.append('_' + i)
      ...:     else:
      ...:         l.append(i)
      ...: 
In [1747]: s = ''.join(l)

In [1748]: s
Out[1748]: '_Stack_Over_Flow'
```

**OR `List Comprehension`:**

```
s = ''.join(['_' + i if i.isupper() else i for c,i in enumerate(list(s))])
```

Comment: This is broken when a capital letter appears twice. Try it with `s = 'SoSoS'`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fixed. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that does exactly what you asked in the question

```
def adding_beforeCapitalLetters(n):
    newstring=''
    for i in range(0,len(n)):
        if (n[i]>='A' and n[i]<='Z'):
            newstring = newstring + '_' + n[i]
        else:
            newstring = newstring + n[i];
    return newstring;
    


print(adding_beforeCapitalLetters("StackOverFlow"));
```